# How to make element visible on history.back action with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

I need a solution which makes element visible after history.back triggered.

Initially, the `div` is hidden on a page. After a user clicks the button, the `div` becomes visible. Then then user visits another link and load page2. When user clicks Back button on browser from page2, I want to make the `div` is still visible on page1.

Page1 - HTML:

```
<html>
 ...
 <body>
   <div class="the-div hidden">
     <h4>You see me now!</h4>
   </div>
   <button onclick="foo()">Click me!<button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Page1 - JS:

```
foo = function(){
  $(".the-div").removeClass("hidden");
 // Expects the code here with history.pushState or something ..
}
```

Comment: You need to store the page state to do that. Can store in in localStorage and read localStorage when page loads...or store remotely

Comment: have a google for history.pushState

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore localStorage.

localStorage.setItem('buttonClicked', false);

on click of button, change the value of localStorage